# How can I know the base url used in a running test in protractor?

Tags: protractor, angular-cli, e2e-testing

I'm trying to do navigation test in protractor and don't see any consitency with the baseUrl in the config and the url used in the test.

protractor.conf.js

```
exports.config = {
  baseUrl: 'http://localhost:4200/'
}
```

navbar.e2e-spec.ts

```
import { NavbarPage } from './navbar.po';
import * as protractor from './../protractor.conf.js';
describe('navbar', () => {
  let navbar: NavbarPage;
  const baseUrl = protractor.config.baseUrl; 

  beforeEach(() => {
    navbar = new NavbarPage();
    browser.get('/');
  });
  it(`should see showcase nav item, be able to (click) it,
  and expect to be navigated to showcase page`, () => {
    const anchorShowcase = navbar.anchorShowcase;
    expect(anchorShowcase.isDisplayed()).toBe(true);
    anchorShowcase.click();
    browser.waitForAngular();
    expect(browser.getCurrentUrl()).toBe(baseUrl + '/showcase');
  });
});
```

Although when I run the e2e test it uses a different port:

```
** NG Live Development Server is listening on localhost:49154, open your browser on http://localhost:49154/ **
```

Why is the test url set to port 49154. This apparently seems to be the default if you start a new angular-cli project: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli

How can I get control over the baseUrl / Or is `http://localhost:49154/` safe to use for all my angular cli projects?

Answer (score 2):

By default when you do `ng e2e` the command take `--serve` value as `true`. It means it will build and serve at that in a particular URL. Not the baseUrl you passed in `protractor.conf.js`

that is why, you are getting a random URL served when testing you app like `http://localhost:49154/`

Now as you don't want build during test and want to test existing build  (URL) like `http://localhost:4200/` you need to pass `--no-serve` in your command line and it will pick `baseUrl` from the `protractor.conf.js`

you can also pass `baseUrl` in the command line like below. note that this not `baseUrl` but `--base-href=`

```
ng e2e --no-serve --base-href=https://someurl.com:8080
```

Answer (score 1):

When running Angular CLI's `ng e2e` command, it states in the wiki that the default port will be random, as seen here:

https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/e2e

Under the `serve` submenu.

The `e2e` command can take in all the same arguments as `serve` so to keep the port the same just pass in `--port my-port-number` to the `ng e2e` command.

As far as that port being safe to use, I wouldn't use it, it is just a random port after all.  I would stick to the default unless you have a use-case for changing it.  The port is mainly relevant for the dev server, not so much for where ever the production code runs.

Answer (score 0):

Aniruddha Das's solution doesn't work anymore as this option isn't there from Angular CLI 6.x version, you can try following -

```
ng e2e --dev-server-target=
```

please see following [reference](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/10761)